# Adsense Management API "Rate Limit Exceeded" error

Tags: google-api, adsense-api

I'm facing with "Rate Limit Exceeded" error with Adsense management API every day around midnight (PDT), when I say around, I mean both before and after midnight. The problem clearly isn't with daily request quota, since I make very few requests and the overview in the Google API console also says the quota is fine, currently I see 4 requests used out of 10000.

However, even when I tried to push the request directly through the Google API console, I'm getting the error. The response shown when I send request through the API explorer in the API console is: "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "rateLimitExceeded", "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"

The error appears every day 1-3 hours before midnight and disapears about 45 minutes after midnight. I have also set the Per-user limit to 10 requests/second/user (even though I'm not sending more than one request every few minutes)

Does anyone have any clue how could I fix this and what could be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Well it just got worse and I'm experiencing it even like 10 hours before the end of the day, thus effectively not beeing able to get any data from the API for the rest of the day. Quota shows 3% of daily limit used and request per second chart shows the maximum of 0.0444 requests per second for the last day, so I really have no idea what's wrong here...

Comment: Apart from the limits in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/appendix/limits), if you run very large reports (millions of rows) you may hit other limits. What report are you trying to generate?

Comment: That might be the case, since I have found out that the current month report usually causes this error and there is quite a lot of pageviews per day on the account I'm generating the report for. The report is a summary report for current month that includes pageviews, clicks, CTR, CPC, RPM and earnings. However I don't know why it triggers an error that is reset only after the following midnight, it would be sufficient if just that long report failed, not affecting any future reports.

Comment: The number of metrics doesn't impact the number of rows (pageviews, clicks, ctrs...). What makes reports grow very fast is a big combination of dimensions. Check out the [article on metrics and dimensions](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/reporting/dimensions_metrics) that explains how to choose dimensions. What dimensions are you requesting?

Comment: Ok, you got the point... I have reviewed the code and found that there are reports that include DOMAIN_NAME metrics. However, the website for which we are generating these reports do have automatic subdomains and there are A LOT of them (millions). So this was causing problems. Thanks a lot for the idea!

Comment: We are also struggling with this absolute same problem but the only dimensions we are requesting are date and country_code. We are trying to import historic data btw (2 years). Is there any way to increase this limit?